# Написать рекурсивную функцию, определяющую, является ли заданное натуральное число простым

Tags: java, рекурсия

В итерации понятно как написать:

```
  public static void checkProstoeChislo(int number) {

        int count = 0;

        for(int i = 1; i < number+1; i++) {
            if(number % i == 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(count);

        if(count == 2) {
            System.out.println("prsotoe");
        } else {
            System.out.println("ne prostoe");
        }

    }
```

А вот как сделать в рекурсии. Я создаю метод с 2 числами(одно число и туда и туда вгоняю), рекурсией доходу до условия `number == 1`, и хочу чтобы вот здесь рекурсия начала вызывать назад все числа и проверить деление на число.

Но так как это рекурсия она делает действие и продолжает закрывать, открытый ранее метод. Вопрос как можно сделать подсчет?

```
    public static int checkRecursionProstoeChislo(int number,int secondNumber) {

        int count = 0;

        if(number == 1) {
            return number;
        }
         if(secondNumber % (checkRecursionProstoeChislo(number-1,secondNumber))  == 0) {
             count++;
         }
               if(count == 2) {
                   System.out.println("prsotoe");
               } else {
                   System.out.println("ne prostoe");
               }

        return count; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня получилось следующее решение:

```
private static boolean isPrime(int number) {
    if (number == 0 || number == 1)
        return true;

    return div(number, 2);
}

private static boolean div(int number, int divider) {
    if (number == divider)
        return true;

    if (number % divider == 0)
        return false;
    else
        return div(number, divider + 1);
}
```

Comment: Нда, что-то я привык только отнимать чтобы прогнать рекурсию
Про + то и забыл.

Очень классное решение, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Например вот так:

```
public static void prime(int n, int s){
    if(n == 1){
        System.out.println("prostoe");
    }else if(s % n == 0){
        System.out.println("ne prostoe");
    }else{
        r(n-1, s);
    }
}
```

Вызов prime(11, 12); вернет **ne prostoe**
Вызов prime(10, 11); вернет **prostoe**

Для удобства использования можно добавить функцию старта

```
public static void test(int n){
    prime(n-1, n);
}
```

Comment: но тут именно что одно число надо проверить.(Является ли число - простым или нет). 
Просто в своей вариации я указывал одно и тоже число два раза.

В вашей это выглядело бы prime(11,11).
И в этом случае в вашей реализации выдает - не простое.

Так собственно у меня и был вопрос, как в рекурсивной функции задать счетчик чтобы он не обнулялся.